# Software to search for MTG decks based on a list of cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I haven't played MTG for a while, but I still own about 500 cards. Some of them were from *pre-built* decks, but now the cards are all randomized.

I have the full inventory (quantity and name) on a text file. Although I've seen a lot of programs that allow you to build and share decks, I'm looking for something that *searches* for a deck based on the cards you have (or on a list you provide).

---

**Update:** I may have misguided you with my explanation, so here it goes in different words. I want to know what decks are out there that I can build with the cards **I have**. Something like: here's the list of cards I possess; show me what decks exist that I can build with them, without needing to buy more cards.

Comment: Are you looking for the decklists of the pre-built decks? Or for general deckslists that use those cards?

Comment: [Something like this](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/102/is-there-anything-like-a-recipe-generator-for-lego-models), but for MTG, not Lego?

Comment: That's **exactly** what I am looking for!

Comment: So both official pre-built decks and famous tournament decks? Or do you want to include decks built by Jane Average player too?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Sky's the limit...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by this post I've managed to implement the requested feature in my program [Mtgdb.Gui](https://github.com/NikolayXHD/Mtgdb/wiki), it's *free* and *opensource*.

The screenshot below shows the list of decks filtered by a condition that you own 90% or more from the Main deck.

[image: screenshot]

So to search the decks based on cards you have collected, you need to

**Step 0.** Import the decks to Mtgdb.Gui. It can be be done as easy as drag-n-dropping a bunch of files or folders into it. See [Wiki](https://github.com/NikolayXHD/Mtgdb/wiki/2.1-Drag-n-drop-or-paste-from-Clipboard-to-import-decks-from-websites) for details.  I used [Forge](https://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=26) to quickly download ~5000 decks.

**Step 1.** Import your collection to Mtgdb.Gui. E.g. you can import from a plain-text file where each row is more or less like this:

```
2 Accomplished Automaton
```

You can also [import your Magic The Gathering Online collection](https://github.com/NikolayXHD/Mtgdb/wiki/2.2-Import-collection-&-decks-from-Magic-The-Gathering-Online).

**Step 2a.** Sort the list of decks by percent of cards from Main deck you own in descending order, by clicking the corresponding field.

**Step 2b.** Alterternatively as in the screenshot above, you can filter the list of decks by using search input.

P.S. Let me stress it, I am the author of [Mtgdb.Gui](https://github.com/NikolayXHD/Mtgdb/wiki). It has to be perfectly clear, because the rules of this forum, as well as common human honesty, I believe, require people to be explicit when promoting their own product.

Comment: This looks very promising.  Thank you for your contribution to the MtG community!  I am a brewer at heart so tools like this are wonderful to me.  Shoebox is never updated and Superbrew has a very limited subset of decks to choose from.  Thanks!!

Comment: I Really appreciate you taking time to write some kind words, thanks!

Comment: Just tried out Mtgdb.gui, and it looks great! Could you please elaborate on how you downloaded all the decks with Forge?

Comment: First download net decks as in [screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12046452/46102585-5dc32680-c1d7-11e8-8241-864ed503ab5b.jpg) . Then find downloaded decks at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Forge\decks\net\

Comment: A single [downloadable](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12rASIUDe2FOOktegUP8qLKTkS_W93qNS) file with all Forge net decks  as per 2018-10-04.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the aforementioned sites, Star City Games' [deck database](https://old.starcitygames.com/decks/search) also has a number of decklists from various formats, searchable both by individual cards and combinations of cards.

With that said, I think the thrust of the question is somewhat misguided; if the goal is to be *competitive* then you'll have much more luck by making strategic trades and the occasional purchase rather than building to the needs of your current collection.  If the intent is somewhat more casual, then I think there's an argument to be made that much of the enjoyment comes out of building your own and exploring (or discovering!) cards and interactions that you hadn't paid close attention to before.  If all you want to do is play the *game* (as opposed to the deckbuilding 'game'), you're probably better off either with preconstructed product or with a limited format (draft or, if you really want to stick with your present collection, a homemade cube built from the materials 'at hand' - see [What Is A Cube? on cubedrafting.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20150207042127/www.cubedrafting.com/what-is-the-cube/) for an introduction to the subject).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for competitive decklists, [MtgTop8](http://www.mtgtop8.com/search) has a nice deck database that you can query by card name (even several cards at a time).

On the other hand, if you want a place where you can build your decklists and share them, [TappedOut](http://tappedout.net/mtg-decks/search/?q=) is a pretty popular site. They don't feature a "card name" field in their search engine, but they do look into card names for matches.

If you're looking for the original pre-built decklists, [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic%3a_The_Gathering_theme_decks) compiles all the links to the official Wizards of the Coast site.

Answer (score 2):

[Shoebox](http://www.shoeboxmtg.com/decksearch.php) is almost what you want. It's new, so  at the moment you can only compare your collection to top decks on TCGplayer.com between certain dates. There's also MTG Goldfish's SuperBrew feature, which wasn't worth it for my small collection either. Cube it is!

Comment: https://www.mtggoldfish.com/superbrew 
that's exactly what he is looking for but you do need a premium accout

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_theme_decks
This is a list of pre-build decks if you know what set there from you should be able to find your deck.

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I was looking for, but useful nonetheless.

Comment: I doubt the thing you looking for exists, at least not for the standard mtg decks.

Answer (score 0):

[MTGA Assistant](https://mtgaassistant.net/) provides that kind of functionality, showing decks that are being used and winning in the current meta, and how many cards you are missing from that deck, if any. It is focused on using your digital collection in Arena rather than your physical card collection. The developers of that app also run [Aetherhub](https://aetherhub.com/), which does let you add your physical collection - I am not sure if they have the same deck building functionality built in as they do for the MTGA app, but it might be worth checking out if you want something like that for physical cards.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Deckcheck](http://www.deckcheck.de/search.php) has a nice search function if you want to do it yourself.  If you just want to play and don't enjoy the deck building all that much (which probably is mine and my friends favorite part) I think the best result will come from help of others.

- Ask your friend who likes deck building.
- Make it a challenge at a MtG forum.
- Ask for help at a forum.
- Use it as a cube.

But I strongly suggest that you have a go at it yourself. Maybe you'll enjoy it :)